# Better way to have classes talk to eachother on behalf of ONE class

Tags: c#, module, worker, worker-thread

I really am not sure what was the best way to title this.

In this example I have the following **WorkerThread** class

```
 class WorkerThread
 {
    public int Id;

    public WorkerThread(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // Thread code.
    }
 }
```

This class is instantiated X times in my program depending on how many threads I want running and **each instance runs in a new Thread()**.

Now the important thing here is that the operation it does is complex, so I create different classes that will behave as **modules** for this WorkerThread class, for example:

```
class Browser
{
    private WorkerThread WorkerThread;

    public Browser(WorkerThread workerThread)
    {
        WorkerThread = workerThread;
    }

    public void Launch()
    {

    }

    public void Close()
    {

    }

    public void NavigateTo()
    {

    }
}
```

Another module.

```
class ProductFinder
{
    private WorkerThread WorkerThread;

    private Browser Browser { get { return WorkerThread.Browser; } }

    public ProductFinder(WorkerThread workerThread)
    {
        WorkerThread = workerThread;
    }

    private void GoToEbay()
    {
        Browser.NavigateTo("http://ebay.com");
    }

    public void FindProduct()
    {
        GoToEbay();
        // Do other stuff.
    }
}
```

It is important to notice here that each module class will contain a reference to the WorkerThread that instantiated it so it can talk to the other modules of the same thread.

Finally the WorkerModule has to use these modules in some way so it can also act as a bridge for the modules to communicate with eachother.

```
class WorkerThread
{
    public int Id;

    public Browser Browser;
    public ProductFinder ProductFinder;

    public WorkerThread(int id)
    {
        Id = id;

        ResetModules();
    }

    private void ResetModules()
    {
        Browser = new Browser(this);
        ProductFinder = new ProductFinder(this);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Browser.Launch();
        ProductFinder.FindProduct();
        Browser.Close();
    }
}
```

Notice how I can make the **ProductFinder** use the browser by having a property with a getter that gets the **Browser** from the **WorkerThread** that instantiated this class.

**So the question is if is there a better way to get a reference to the Browser in the ProductFinder?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If these operations act in a series I would suggest that you use System.Threading.Task.Task.Task<> instead of rolling your own worker thread management. Each step in a job would then submit the next stap. Other than that I too am not sure what the question is.

Comment: sorry, i dont know how i left that. I updated with the question in bold at the end